# Why I can't find the "App\Extensions\RiakUserProvider" namespace in my Laravel project following this "Adding a custom provider" tutorial?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-authorization

I am absolutely new to **PHP** and **Laravel**.

I am working on a **Laravel 5.3** application and I have to use a custom web service to check the user credential so I am trying to follow this official tutorial about **Adding a custom provider** to handle user access: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers. So, in theory it seems pretty simple but I am finding some difficulties.

As you can see in the previous tutorial as first step it modify the **App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider** class contained into the Laravel project.

So, I have modified my **AuthServiceProvider** according to the tutorial example obtaining this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Extensions\RiakUserProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        // CUSTOM CODE:
        Auth::provider('riak', function ($app, array $config) {
            // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider...

            return new RiakUserProvider($app->make('riak.connection'));
        });
    }
}
```

The problem is that it can't find the **App\Extension** namespace, this:

```
use App\Extensions\RiakUserProvider;
```

PhpStorm signs **Exstensions** in red saying **"Undefined Extensions namespace"** so it can't use the **RiakUserProvider** class in my code.

Why? Do I have to add some dependencies in Composer? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

What exactly is the **RiakUserProvider** class?

What exactly does this code:

```
Auth::provider('riak', function ($app, array $config) {
    // Return an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider...

    return new RiakUserProvider($app->make('riak.connection'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Laravel docs the `RiakUserProvider` class is just an example custom User Provider. Class is located in `App\Extensions` namespace, but the actual provider class content was not provided.

If you want to create a custom User Provider you should create a folder named `Extensions` in your `App` folder and create `RiakUserProvider.php` file containing `RiakUserProvider` class. This follows [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) class autoloading standard.

When you create your own User Provider please make sure it implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider` interface.

Here is a nice step by step tutorial of creating one:

https://www.georgebuckingham.com/laravel-52-auth-custom-user-providers-drivers